# Jacquet module of unramified principal series representaion with respect to parabolic subgroup of $GL_n(F)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, induced-representations

Let $F$ be a local field of characteristic zero and $G=\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$.

Let $B=UT$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$ and $\chi=(\chi_1,\cdots,\chi_n)$ is an unramified character of $B$.

Consider unramified principal series $\pi$ of $G$ defined by $\operatorname{Ind}_B^G \chi$.

Then it is known that the Jacquet module $J_{U}(\pi)= \bigoplus_{w \in W(G)} \chi^{w} \cdot \delta_{B}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $W$ is Weyl group and $\delta_{B}$ is the modulus character of $B$.

Let $P=NM$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$ whose Levi $M$ is $\operatorname{GL}_{a} \times \operatorname{GL}_{n-a}$ for some positive integer $1\le a < n$.

Then I want to know $J_{N}(\pi)$. Is there a result or conjecture on this at least even in the unramified case?

Comment: I think it should be exactly the sum of the unramified representations of $M$ whose Jacquet modules with respect to the Borel of $M$ are $J_U(\pi)$. I think you can prove this using the Bruhat decomposition to calculate the corestriction of the induction.

Comment: @Sawin, Thank you very much for your comments. But do you think is it hard to describe it explicitly?

Comment: No, I don't think it's hard at all. I think it's relatively easy, I just haven't done it yet -  in part, because I believe there's probably a good reference for it somewhere and there's a reasonable chance someone will just find it and post it here.

Comment: By what I said it should be $\bigoplus_{w \in W(G)/ W(M)} \operatorname{Ind}_{B'}^M  \chi^{w} \cdot \delta_{B}^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \delta_{B'}^{- \frac{1}{2}}$ where $B'$ is the Borel of $M$. That said I am a bit confused by your formula - shouldn't $\chi$ itself appear in the sum somewhere?

Comment: @Wii Sawin, Thank you very much for your kind comments. Yes! $\chi$ apprears in the formula I wrote for identity element in Weyl group.

Comment: But what about the $\delta_B^{1/2}$ term? Could it be $ \chi \cdot \delta_B^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \delta_B^{- \frac{w}{2}} $?